# Send a request from dialogflow to an application on google cloud app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I wrote a python code (test.py) and deployed on google app engine which is running in the background that includes 2 functions (find_music, read_csv), I want to send a request from dialogflow webhook and call a function (find_music) from that file and get the result, then send it to dialogflow.

In other words, I am going to send a request from google action to play a music but I should get the link of the file from the function that I've created.

I googled a lot, but I couldn't find a solution to call a function. Maybe the way I do is wrong. I'd be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Are you using a web framework with Python? (I.e. Flask or Django)

If so, you could send an HTTP request to your Python server from inside Dialogflow's fulfillment.

By using different routes, you could call either function. Flask example:

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():
    return "Hello, world!"

Comment: Thanks for replying. No, I don't use a web framework.